# TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;text&#39; of undefined

Tags: mongodb, express

```
router.post('/addtodo', (req, res, next) => {
let todo = new Todos({
    text: req.body.text,
    date: new Date(),
  });
Todos.addTodo(todo, (err, todos, next) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.json(todos);
});
});
```

I am trying to save a document in the Todo schema using the above method
Schema and methods are as follows

```
const todoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
text: {
    type: String
},
date: {
    type: Date, 
    default: Date.now 
}
});
const Todos = module.exports = mongoose.model('todos', todoSchema);

//Retrieve documents
module.exports.getTodos = (callback) => {
Todos.find(callback);
};

//Add document
module.exports.addTodo = (todo, callback) => {
Todos.create(todo, callback);
};
```

But when I try to POST a json object using postman it shows this error.

```
 <body>
    <pre>TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;text&#39; of undefined
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at router.post (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\router\todoroute.js:18:24)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.handle (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at router (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at expressInit (C:\Users\shahaji.shinde\Desktop\practice\todo-mean\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    </pre>
</body>
```

The error is in the first code snippet- line number 3.

Comment: Check if req is not null and body is not null

Comment: I am using postman to send POST request, I am sure the body is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible causes come to my mind with the information you posted:
 - It can be because you are not sending the appropriate Content-Type: application/json  (check it).
 - Server is not ready to parser json:
For that, you should have something like this:

```
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyparser.json({limit: '10mb'}));
```

Let me know if it helps you

Comment: I am sending the appropriate content type

Comment: You are right about the parser. In the main file `app.js` I imported the parser middleware `body-parser.json()` after the router module `router.js` which is why the router module was unable to access the parser. This helped! Thankyou